# Design Database for repeated events

Tags: sql-server, database, database-schema

I'm trying to design a database table for storing events that occurs at different intervals, 
--daily, eg. everday around 10am
--every tue,mon and wed of a week,
--monthly, eg. 1st of every month
--twice a month, eg. 3rd and 4th of every month

How can I achieve this with simple database design. Any help, suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the UI with the backend. You need to create the following tables:

```
intervals(interval_id, name, repeat_time_span)
events(event_id, interval_id, name, created)
```

You need to implement the CRUD to handle `intervals` and `events` insertion, modification, deletion and view. You need to link UI controls (like a form and a grid) to enable user interaction with the `events` and `intervals` and to implement any advanced logic regarding those.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry about the tittle of my question. I edited it. I need to store the values for the intervals as well (not just the name) so that I can know when is the event sheduled.

Comment: I have modified the structure of intervals to handle your needed requirement.